# PyCharm: How do I get rid of this tooltip documentation window?

Tags: pycharm

I see this whenever I hover my mouse on any variable or names in my code.

[image: 1]

How can I reset all values to defaults in my PyCharm? I see 2 settings options under file menu, which one of this is intended for global settings ? What's the point of having 2 settings when they both have the same options. Is it project specific application?

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

`Settings | Inspections -- there is "Reset To Default" tool button (Ctrl+R is default shortcut on Windows)`

Or you can delete the file profile. it will recreate a default profile next time you will run pycharm

Comment: I dint find this option in my 'Inspections'. Could you please post a screenshot ? What version of pycharm are you using ?